# How to find a stock price on a particular date?

Tags: r, quantmod, tidy, quandl

Using quantmod or tidy quant, it is possible to download stock price from a range of period. However, I am looking to add a stock price column to an existing data frame which has ticker and date in it. In google spreadsheet, there is a simple formula to find the stock price on a particular date.

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("AMZN","price",date(2017,2,7))`

However, in R, there seems to be no way to do it.

What I have is a data frame:

```
Date.    Ticker.  Revenue.  Profit...

x.          y        z        i      
...         ...      ...      ...
```

I need to add an additional column with stock price of y as on x, to get

```
Date.    Ticker.  Revenue.  Profit...   Price

x.          y        z        I          p (of y on x)
...         ...      ...      ...        ...
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use tiingo together with quantmod"(or tidyquant). I would expect yahoo to work as well, but when using yahoo I keep running into errors when using 1 day retrievals (shoddy work on the yahoo side of things).

```
library(quantmod)
my_api <- "my_api" # <- here goes your tiingo api
amzn <- getSymbols("AMZN", auto.assign = FALSE, 
                   src = "tiingo",
                   api = my_api,
                   from = "2017-02-07",
                   to = "2017-02-07")

amzn
           AMZN.Open AMZN.High AMZN.Low AMZN.Close AMZN.Volume
2017-02-07    809.31    816.16    807.5      812.5     3466091
```

Combining everything in a data.frame:

```
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_api <- "my_api"  # <- here goes your tiingo api


# helper function to just get the close price
get_price <- function(ticker, date) {
  data <- getSymbols(ticker, 
                    auto.assign = FALSE, 
                    src = "tiingo",
                    api = my_api,
                    from = date,
                    to = date)
  
  out <- as.numeric(quantmod::Cl(data))
  out
}


my_data %>% 
  mutate(close = map2(ticker, date, get_price))

        date ticker revenue profit close
1 2017-02-07   AMZN   10000     10 812.5
2 2018-03-05   MSFT   20000     20 93.64
```

data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(date = c("2017-02-07", "2018-03-05"),
                      ticker = c("AMZN", "MSFT"),
                      revenue = c(10000, 20000),
                      profit = c(10, 20))
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is how to add that price to the existing df, as show in the question

Comment: @azmath, see additional info in answer. Next time please create a bit more of a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @phiver, thank you! However, I cannot replicate. It shows an error:  Error: `Problem with `mutate()` input `close`.
x Unable to import “AMZN”.
HTTP error 401.
ℹ Input `close` is `map2(ticker, date, get_price)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.``

Comment: I have actually seen similar error before when I tried to put from and to date same

Comment: @azmath, Can you supply a small `dput` of your data.frame? Looks as if your dates might not be in the expected format.

Comment: Here you go: `dput(FundwCF$date)`
...16800, 17166, 15339, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17166, 15430, 
15795, 16160, 16525, 16891, 17256), class = "Date"

Comment: Actually I ran the exact code you gave to test, and it gives the error Error:  Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `close`.
x Unable to import “AMZN”.
HTTP error 401.
ℹ Input `close` is `map2(ticker, date, get_price)`.

Comment: Here is the traceback: Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. 
24.
stop(fallback) 
23.
signal_abort(cnd) 
22.
abort(c(cnd_bullet_header(), bullets, i = if (show_group_details) cnd_bullet_cur_group_label()), 
    class = c("dplyr:::mutate_error", "dplyr_error"), error_name = error_name, 
    error_expression = error_expression) 
...

Comment: I think even tinigo doesn't work: 'getSymbols("AMZN", 
           auto.assign = FALSE, 
           src = "tiingo",
           api = my_api,
           from = "01/01/2020",
           to = "01/01/2020")' shows error: Error in getSymbols.tiingo(Symbols = "AMZN", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “AMZN”.
HTTP error 401.

Comment: You do have an api for tiingo don't you? You can get one for free from them.

Comment: Omg, I'm such an amateur. I literally copied my_api lol Let me try that

Comment: Mutate is successful in my data frame, adds new variable "close", and shows no error! But returns no new row? Could it because the data frame is large? It goes back to 1980s, with more than 100K rows of stock fundamentals

Comment: Here is the return: [1] GCK                        year                       date                      
 [4] ticker                     company                    industry                  
 [7] sales                      COGS                       EBT                       
[10] Operating_income_after_dep Nonoperating_income        assets                    
[13] liabilities                equity                     receivables  ...             
[22] Acquisitions               income_tax                 close                     
**<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)**

Comment: And this is the dput: `structure(numeric(0), class = "Date")`

Comment: And used this to transform: `FundwCF <- transform(FundwCF, date = as.Date(as.character(date), "%Y%m%d"))`